# Patterns for handling scheduled/unscheduled downtime using ServiceStack and WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, servicestack

Now that we have webservices running, we need to make changes to db, servers etc. so ..

wondering if there are any patterns for handling planned and unplanned downtime using ServiceStack and also using webapi for older projects in a planned fashion rather than letting exceptions fly as they may

Of course happy to roll our own but thought to check first !